# Exception Handling UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I started to write my first program for UWP (Universal Windows Platform). I like C# and I read about try-catch block to get exceptions.
I have a special structure in my app and I want to get some advice for the best kind of exception handling.

My setup is as follows:
I have a page called **MainPage** with a method **GetInformation**.
I have two classes, named **GetSetting** and **GetConnection**. With **GetInformation** of the **MainPage** I get input from the user and send them to **GetConnections**. In that method I then call **GetSetting** (nested method).

This is my structure. Now I know that an error can happen in every part: the user inputs not valid, or I can't get a connection to the form systems, maybe can't access settings files, or some other errors. So I've added try-catch blocks to each part of my app (so in **GetInformation**, **GetConnection**, **GetSetting**).

- I read about Message Dialog but it is an asynchronously method: If I try to add a message dialog to each part of the application but if there is an error in each one then I get 3 message dialog for my errors. I don't want to make my app unclear by adding task and await to all my methods because it is only one part of my app. I couldn't find any way for stop in my application and force to wait for user input. So I stopped using this way.
- I tried a second way: I add a control in my **MainPage** to show an error message. This gives me another problem: There is no way to return from all nested methods (I looked for one but I didn't find it). But inside **GetConnection** and **GetSetting** I have no access to the UI elements. So I have to throw the exception inside of my try-catch block again until I get to the **MainPage**. But with this approach I can't show any special information about that exception. I want to keep my exception and I don't want to make new exception and throw that to **MainPage** becasue StackTrace is readonly so I can't set it for my new exception so I only throw the exception that is created by app and I can't add any special information.

These are my ways and both have some problems. What is the best way for  exception handling in this situation.

Update:

```
public string GetInformation()
{
    // Some codes here
    var data = GetConnection();
    // Some code here that use data
    // Some other codes
}
public string GetConnection() // In class Connection
{
    // Some codes here
    var data = GetSetting();
    // Some code here that use data
    // Some other codes
}
public string GetSetting() // in class Setting
{
    // Some codes here
}
```

This is my code. in every part of codes like "some codes here" can error happen. 
What is the best way?

Comment: What do you want to do when you get an exception?

Comment: I want to show information such the place of method that error happened like myApp.GetInformation and some other information then a button for send report to me.

Comment: So you want to stop the further execution of the `GetInformation()` method when you got an error. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. exactly this is my problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can return when you catch an Exception and Display your message

```
public void Get()
{
    //Your code

    string returnValue;
    try
    {
        returnValue = GetInformation();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return;
    }

    //Code that will not cause exception

    try
    {
        //Another possible line of causing exception
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //Error Message
        return;
    }

    //Codes that will not cause exception
}

public string GetInformation()
{
    try
    {
        //Your Code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Error message
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but my problem is information!! I can only return null or string.empty for method that return string or object But I can't do anything for int or double or etc (because maybe 0 is my answer) and another problem is I can't send special information. I can validate value at parent method but I can't get any information that I want to get from place that error happened. for example some special values or etc.

Comment: @Bor I have updated the answer. You can catch the `Exception` in the parent method.

Comment: Thanks again but maybe you don't understand my question. if any error happened then I catch it in Get method so I don't know from where I come because I catch it in Get method. If I catch it in the GetInformation Method then because app doesn't stop after show message so if any other errors happen in Get I will show another message. So I get two message. It is problem of message and I need something else.

Comment: so think that after "var returnValue = GetInformation(); " we have some other codes and maybe another error happen.  so I want to make a good message for that in try-catch block. so I add a message in catch block of Get method. so with you code and my change I get two message!

Comment: @Bor So when do you want to display the message?

Comment: I want to show message for **each method with error** and show appropriate message **for each method** but because application execute after catch exception I get more than one message if there is an error in each method. so I want to know what I can I do?

Comment: @Bor First of all there's going to be only one exception as the program won't proceed further, so the lines after the line of exception won't be executed. So, you are not going to see any more exceptions.

Comment: I edited your code so you will understand my question. Now I get two message! I can't stop app for get user input for first message because in UWP when you show a message, the code after message will be executed.

Comment: @Bor You should not enclose all of your codes` into a single `try catch` block. For every possible line of exception, there should be different `try catch` block. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I use your way and I set Source of exception in nested method to something special like ".../CommonClass" and I throw that exception and in the parent method I check Source for get 3 points and if there is nothing I set new source and I throw it again. I do this Until I get to my MainPage method and I show message there. so I use Source for my information but I didn't see throw exception in catch block like your code before! I can't vote up because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Validation() method in your final step to get errors, if any, could occurred or not.

```html
GetInformation()
{
  return information;  
}

GetConnection()
{
    return connection;
}
GetSetting()
{
    return setting;
}
```

Now in your MainPage include the Validation() method and implement your logic to show the results in one messageDialog()

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Can you explain more? I add some more information to my question.

Comment: Hi @Bor, if you get any error in the // some codes part // use a bool variable or append an "error string" to the returned variable. So that, in validation method, you can identify the erro criteria and notify in the messageDialog

Comment: Do you mean return a bool value for validation. It's make my app unclear because My method return value that is not bool so I have to use tuple for return two or more value and I have to validate tuple.Item1, etc so it's very unclear.